# JQuery multiple click event?

Tags: jquery

There are two div in my page.

```
<div id="test-1000"></div>
<div id="test-1111"></div>
```

In view of above single click event source jQuery is:

```
$('#test-1000').click(function(){});
```

But how to achieve two div with a similar to the above statement click events to be monitored are, and how to distinguish between div, which is the click event?

Comment: the event passed into the click event will hold a reference to the actual element that was clicked, so you can easily identify it by that method... normally [ .click(function(evt){evt.target}) ]

Answer (score 10):

I'll use a common class attribute to group all the target elements

```
<div class="test" id="test-1000" data-id="1000"></div>
<div class="test" id="test-1111" data-id="1111"></div>
```

then

```
$('.test').click(function(){
    //here this.id will give the clicked div id and this will refer the clicked dom element
    //$(this).data('id') will give 1000/1111
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `$(this)` in the callback function to know 'which' element the event fired on.

```
$('.test').click( function() {
    alert( $(this).attr('id') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to go with data attribute and class approach

HTML code

```
<div class="test" data="0000">1</div>
<div class="test" data="1111">2</div>
```

js

```
$('.test').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr("data"));
});
```

sample [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashukasama/EHWYx/)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you don't want or can't modify your html, you can use [jquery "starts-with" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
<div id="test-1000"></div>
<div id="test-1111"></div>

$("[id^='test']").on('click', function(){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7FKa/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
  <div class="test" id="test-1000" data-id="1000"></div>
    <div class="test" id="test-1111" data-id="1111"></div>
```

Js

```
$('.test').click(function(){
    //here this.id will give the clicked div id and this will refer the clicked dom element
    //$(this).data('id') will give 1000/1111
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like:

```
document.getElementById("test-1000").onclick = function(){});
```

You can not use the element before it is defined.